# How to prove the limit of the empirical distribution function?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

I am reading about [Exchangeability and de Finetti's theorem](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/%7Esteffen/teaching/grad/definetti.pdf) and the example in slide 11 confuses me. Consider $(X_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $\forall n \in \mathbb{N},\ X_1,\cdots,X_n \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma)$ with $$\Sigma_{ii} = 1,\ \Sigma_{ij} = \rho \neq 0,\ for\ i \neq j$$
I wonder how to prove that $$F(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n\chi_{(-\infty,x]}(X_i)}{n}=\Phi\left(\frac{x-Y}{\sqrt{1-\rho}}\right)$$
where $$Y=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}{n}$$
I don't know how to start with it since $\chi_{(-\infty,x]}(X_i)$ and $\chi_{(-\infty,x]}(X_j)$ are not independent.